# In neo4j, how to club nodes together into groups and have relationships between these groups?

Tags: neo4j, rdf, data-modeling, graph-databases

I want to club nodes and their relations together (like [triplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplestore)) and have relations going between such triplets in *neo4j*.

[image: Sample image of the graph]

How can this be done neo4j? Sorry for not showing any of my previous work because I was not able to find anything that was of much use.
I have asked the same thing in neo4j forums, [here](https://community.neo4j.com/t/how-to-club-nodes-together-and-have-relationships-between-such-colection-of-nodes/5681?u=abrocknrol).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT1:**
I have figured out one possible way to do this, need your help to decide weather it will cause some problem with queries or storage.
*Sorry, stackoverflow said I'm not allowed to embed pictures yet*
Possible solution sketch.

[image: Possible solution sketch]

Triplets take the form of **subject** --> **relation** --> **predicate**
So for every triplet I need, I'll make another node representing that triplet.
The triplet will have links to the subject and predicate and can also contain their id as key-value pair. 
In this way we could have relations between 2 triplets.

Comment: *"subject --> relation --> predicate"* - ? I'd say, a triple is usually `subject -- predicate --> object` - you have to nodes and an edge between. And each node as well as the edge is labeled

Comment: Your example graph has the same node coming up multiple times. Do you need multiple copies of the same node (for visualization purposes) or is this more oriented toward storage and query purposes, where you would have only a single node per distinct subject?